# Problem in saving formset in django Updateview

Tags: python, django, formset

I am new in Django and Stackoverflow, so please accept my apology if my codes is not standard.
I try to create a blogging website. Users can create and update posts and each post can have one or more categories or no category. I use form for Post and Formset for Category. However, in Updateview for some reason I couldnt save the formset!!!!

## models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post, 
            blank=True,related_name='categories')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from blogging.models import Post, Category

class PostUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'published_date']

CATEGORY_CHOICES = [('', 'Choose from the list')]
for c in Category.objects.all():
    CATEGORY_CHOICES.append((c, c))


class CategoryUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name']
        labels = {'name': 'Category'}
        help_texts = {'name': 'Choose category for your post'}
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.Select(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
        }


 CategoryFormset = forms.modelformset_factory(Category, 
                                        form=CategoryUpdateForm, extra=1,
                                             max_num=3, can_delete=True)
```

## views.py

```
from blogging.models import Post, Category
from blogging.forms import PostUpdateForm, CategoryFormset

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blogging/post_update.html'
    form_class = PostUpdateForm
    formset_class = CategoryFormset

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']
        if formset.is_valid():
            category_form = formset.save(commit=False)
            category_form.posts.add(self.get_object())
            category_form.save()
            formset.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.POST:
            context['formset'] = self.formset_class(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['formset'] = 
                     self.formset_class(queryset=post.categories.all())
        return context
```

template

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
            {{ u_form | crispy }}
            {{ p_form | crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" 
               type="submit">Update</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could be other issues but check your intention for PostUpdateView. All of the functions there should be indented by 4 spaces so they are methods of the class.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know for indentation. It was just my typo in copying and pasting my code here. I just edited my post to have correct indention. In my real code of course this was not a issue.

Answer (score 0):

I could find the answer. By using extra-view package and use the CreateInlineView, and UpdateInlineView all can be solved. https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/